# Argue $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\cos\frac{1}{\theta}\sin\theta-\theta\cos\frac{1}{\theta}}{\theta} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

My Teacher wants us to argue that this equation below is true. I am just curious how I would actually explain this? I mean I understand how its true but how can I argue this?

$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\cos\frac{1}{\theta}\sin\theta-\theta\cos\frac{1}{\theta}}{\theta} = 0$$

Comment: There is no equation here.

Comment: What do you want to argue? Do you want to argue that $$\lim_{\theta \to 0^+} \dfrac{\cos(1/\theta) \sin(\theta) - \theta \cos(1/\theta)}{\theta} = 0?$$

Comment: Thats what the problem asked which i dont understand

Comment: I guess he wants us to argue that the limit is 0 as it approaches from the right?

Comment: If the problem is to show that the limit is zero, can you please edit that into the question? As it stands, you haven't given an equation, so you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Okay i added it

Comment: @soniccool: I don't understand "u understand how its true": how do you understand that? Also, explaining a little of what you know about limits, and what you've tried already, would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0^+} \cos \left ( 1 \over \theta \right ) \left ( \sin \theta - \theta \over \theta \right)  $$
Let, $ \frac{1}{\theta} = \phi $, then we have for all real values of $ \phi $ $$ -1 \leq  \left ( \cos \phi  \right ) \leq 1 $$

**EDIT::** taking comments into consideration
$$ - \left| \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta} - 1 \right| \le \cos(1/\theta) \left(\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta} - 1 \right) \le \left|\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta} - 1 \right| $$
$$ -1 \times 0 \leq \lim_{\phi \rightarrow \infty } \cos \phi \times \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0 } \left ( \frac{\sin \theta} \theta - 1 \right ) \leq 1 \times 0  $$
$$ \text{Or, using squeeze theorem, we have,  } \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0^+} \cos \left ( 1 \over \theta \right ) \left ( \sin \theta - \theta \over \theta \right)  = 0 $$

Comment: I think I get what you're saying here, but this answer isn't really clear as it is. What do you mean by some value? Where does the zero come from? Why isn't it a problem that we divide by $\theta$ and then take the limit as $\theta$ tends to 0? (As a matter of fact *I* know the answer to these questions. But they're really the substance of the question, and need addressing, IMO)

Comment: Although this answer is essentially correct, I would have been happier to see an explanation along the following lines: If $g$ is a bounded function, say $-M<g(x)<M$ for all $x$ in the domain of $g$, and if $f$ is a function whose limit at $a$ is zero, $a$ being an element of the closure of the domain of $g$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x) = 0$. What’s going on between the parentheses in $\cos(blah)$ is immaterial: that was a red herring.

Comment: The ironic thing is that sometimes, if a high rep user does this, he/she gets many upvotes, but we tend to nit pick when it is another person.

Comment: Dear experimentX, As written, your final line is not correct, since $\lim_{\phi \to \infty} \cos \phi$ does not exist.  In any case, as @Lubin notes, manipulating the argument inside the $\cos$ function is irrelevant.  Regards,

Comment: How would you write it?? the best i can think of it now is $$ -1 \times 0 \leq  \lim_{\phi \rightarrow \infty } \cos \phi \times \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0 } \left ( \frac{\sin \theta} \theta - 1 \right ) \leq 1 \times 0 = 0  $$

Comment: I would write $- \left| \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta} - 1 \right| \le \cos(1/\theta) \left(\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta} - 1 \right) \le \left|\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta} - 1 \right|$, then use the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you  ...

Comment: The limit $\lim_{\phi\rightarrow \infty} \cos{\phi}$ does not exist. We use the facts that the cosine is a bounded function and the limit of the product of a bounded function times another function whose limit is zero is zero.